# I've got a small problem with induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Let me take a quick example:

We want to prove by induction that $3^n-1$ is a multiple of 2, where n is a positive integer.

So we start with our "base case" and show that $3^1-1$ is indeed a multiple of 2.

We then "assume" that $3^{k+1}-1$ will yield the same result and then go on to prove our case:

$3^{k+1}-1=3 \cdot 3^k-1=2 \cdot 3^k+3^k-1$ so because we know that 2 times something must be a multiple of 2, we have proven it for the first part of our equation...But the next part is what bothers me. How can we say that just because it works for $3^1-1$ then it must work for all k? I'm understanding it as if we're 'assuming' that it works for all k but how does that not make the whole proof collapse? You can't just assume in mathematics as far as I know.

Comment: The assumption is not that it works for all k. It's that it works for a particular choice of k.

In other words, you prove that if your proposition is true for a particular number which we denote with "k", then it will work for "k+1" as well. From this and the fact that it works for k=1 it follows that it works for all k.

Answer (score 1):

Say that you are trying to prove that for all $k$, the statement $P(k)$ is true.  (In your case, $P(k)$ is the statement "$3^k-1$ is a multiple of $2$".)

In induction, we prove two things: that $P(1)$ is true (called the "base case") and that the statement "If $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is also true" is true for each $k$, called the "inductive step".

Then we know $P(1)$ is true, by the base case.

Therefore, by the inductive step, $P(2)$ is true.

Therefore, by the inductive step, $P(3)$ is true.

Therefore, by the inductive step, $P(4)$ is true.

And so on, and so on!

Induction can almost be thought of as a machine for generating a proof: it shows you that you COULD prove it directly for any fixed value of $n$, by writing out a proof that passes through $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You have checked that $3^1 -1 = 2$ : so OK for the base case.

Then you must prove that $3^{k+1} - 1 = 2n$, assuming that $3^k - 1 = 2p$.

But : $3^{k+1} - 1 = 3(3^k) - 1 = 3(3^k-1)+2 = 3(2p)+2 = (3p+1)2$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Show that the claim holds for $k_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$
2. Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and show that if the claim holds for $k$, then it holds for $k+1$.
3. Deduce: let $k\geq k_{0}$, then $k=k_{0}+n$. Do you agree with me that you can show in $n$ steps that the claim holds for $k$?

As $k$ was arbitrary, it holds for all $k\geq k_{0}$.

Answer (score 0):

A common analogy for mathematical induction is that of setting up dominoes.

The base case is the first domino that you set up. The next thing, the inductive step says something like "if the $k$'th domino falls, then so will the $k+1$'th domino.

Mathematical induction basically says "If you set up at least one domino and have assured one will knock the next one down, then all the dominos will fall down."

During the inductive step, you assume that $3^k-1$ is divisible by 2. You ask "does that ensure the next domino will fall? That is, will $3^{k+1}-1$ be divisible by 2? You would then seek to relate this step to the last one. Since $3(3^k-1)=3^{k+1}-3=3^{k+1}-1+2$, you can rearrange to find that $3^{k+1}-1=3(3^k-1)-2$, and since both things on the right are divisible by $2$, the thing on the left is divisible by $2$.